# $6 \times 6$ and $7 \times 7$ integer matrices

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

> Can one fill a $6 \times 6$ matrix with integers so that the sum of all the numbers in each $3 \times 3$ square equals $2016$ and the sum of all the numbers in each $5 \times 5$ square equals $2015$?
>
> Solve the same problem for the $7 \times 7$ case.

**My work so far:**

I solved the problem for table $6\times6$:

\begin{bmatrix}
2017 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2017 \\
0 & -6050 & 4033 & 4034 & -6050 & -1 \\
0 & 4034 & -2017 & -2017 & 4033 & 0 \\
0 & 4033 & -2017 & -2017 & 4034 & 0 \\
-1 & -6050 & 4034 & 4033 & -6050 & 0 \\
2017 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2017
\end{bmatrix}

**Addition:**

[image]

I proved that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=4\cdot 2017$

$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=-4$

$x_1+x_3=x_2+x_4$

$S=0$

Further

[image]

**Q:** *How to prove or disprove the existence of the table $7\times7$?*

Comment: Is this question from an on-going contest?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: not yet

Comment: How did you find that $6 \times 6$ matrix that satisfies the given constraints?

Comment: Now I will supplement

Comment: This is a simple, although large, linear algebra problem.  You have 36 variables and $4^2 + 2^2$ sparse linear equations.  If you can solve them (reduced row echelon) then you can solve the problem in rationals.  If the problem can be solved in rationals, then it can be solved in integers using the appropriate multipliers.

Comment: @DanielV How would you solve a linear system of $36$ linear equations in $49$ unknowns using arbitrary-precision rational arithmetic?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I wouldn't use arbitrary precision arithmetic.  Rationals are sufficient, although in this case not necessary since it all works out nicely.

Comment: @DanielV How? MATLAB uses floating-point arithmetic. How are you computing the RREF using rationals? Which rationals? Rationals can be approximated and reduced, or they can grow arbitrarily large.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Software options include sage, maple, mathematica.  It also isn't difficult to implement rational arithmetic and RRE in an arbitrary programming language, such as C++, java, C#.  MATLAB really is pretty much junk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: in the $7 \times 7$ case, how many $3 \times 3$ squares and how many $5 \times 5$ squares contain each entry of the table?

EDIT:
OK, time's up... each entry of the $7 \times 7$ table is in the same number of  $3 \times 3$ squares as it is in $5 \times 5$ squares.  So i you take the sums of the numbers in each $3 \times 3$ square and add them up, you should get the same result as if you take the sum of the numbers in each $5 \times 5$ square and add them up.  Now, what does that tell you?

Comment: squares overlap. For example, it is easy to prove that there is a square $15\times15$. Indeed, it can be divided into $25$ squares of $3\times3$, which means the total amount $25 \cdot 2016$. Square $15x15$ can also be divided into $9$ squares $5\times5$, so the total amount of $9 \cdot 2015$. But $25 \cdot 2016 \not = 9 \cdot 2015$. So, there is a square 15x15. But this technique works only if the squares do not overlap. Square $7\times7$ impossible without  overlap

Comment: Of course the squares overlap.  I don't understand your point.  A $15 \times 15$ square contains $13^2$ $3 \times 3$ squares and $11^2$ $5 \times 5$ squares.  But you didn't answer the question in my hint.

Comment: In the $7 \times 7 -$ $5^2$ $3\times3$ squares and  $2^2$ $5\times5$ squares

Comment: For example, a corner entry is in one $3 \times 3$ square and one $5 \times 5$ square.  What about the others?

Comment: i difficult to answer

Comment: @Roman83 In the $7 \times 7$ case, shouldn't there be **nine** $5 \times 5$ squares?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Yes, nine 5×5 squares. I made a mistake. I do not know how it will help me